# Start-Process with auto elevated permissions and passing command inline

Tags: powershell

I need to start a windows service on the local computer through PS by directly running the PS script w.o the need to manually elevate the permissions. This code works for me:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList "-file MyFileName.ps1"
```

Where `MyFileName.ps1` contains:

```
Start-Service MyServiceName
```

But I want to keep it simple and instead of storing the command into a separate file, I want to run a single script. The following does not work for me:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList "-command '& {Start-Service MyServiceName}'"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start-Process` invokes a new process. The invocation doesn't recognize single quotes as quoting characters, so instead of passing a parameter `-command` with a command string `'&{Start-Service MyServiceName}'` you're passing 4 tokens: `-command`, `'&`, `{Start-Service`, and `MyServiceName}`.

Change this:

```
"-command '& {Start-Service MyServiceName}'"
```

into this:

```
"-command `"& {Start-Service MyServiceName}`""
```